# Verificar se há palavras em maiúsculas

Tags: php

Como verificar se uma string contém palavras em maiúsculas em PHP? Eu tenho uma página de registro, checar isso quando o usuário faz o registro.

Comment: Bem vindo, Veja [como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Como assim? quando achar as letras maiusculas faz o que?

Comment: Pode usar uma regex `[A-Z]`

Comment: Sua pergunta está muito ampla, explique mais o que você quer, dê um exemplo e mostre aonde você quer chegar, recomendo as leituras citadas pelo @rubStackOverflow

Comment: @Brayan Você pode explicar melhor a dúvida? A resposta do rray funcionou? Afinal, você quer saber se o texto tem 1 ou mais letras maiúsculas, saber se ele está todo em maiúsculas, se tem pelo menos uma palavra em maiúsculas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para descubrir se existem letras maiusculas em uma string pode utilizar uma regex simples `[A-Z]` com a função `preg_match()`.

```
<?php
$entradas = ['Um', 'min abc', 'aÇão', 'ação', 'CAPS'];

foreach($entradas as $item){
   if(preg_match('/\p{Lu}/u', $item)){
      echo "Entrada: $item - existe pelo menos uma letra maiuscula\n";
   }else{
      echo "Entrada: $item - não existe pelo menos uma letra maiuscula\n";
   }
}
```

[Exemplo - ideone](http://ideone.com/WeVJ1M)

Comment: `/[A-Z]*/` avalia `''`, `'sominusculas'`, `'qualquercoisa'` para true pois o pattern aceita zero matches devido ao `*`. Mesmo retirando o `*` a solução ainda não é robusta pois não lida com unicode, qualquer `É` ou `Ç` será rejeitado.

Comment: @brunorb, para caracteres Unicode basta adicionar o modificador u. Depois arrumo isso, obrigado pela dica

Comment: @BrunoRB alterei a resposta, está de acordo agora?

Comment: Seu código diz que todas as entradas tem maíusculas, rode para ver. Ele está quase correto, você precisa usar a propriedade `Lu` para especificar que são "uppercase letters", [referência](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php).  No caso a regex correta é `/\p{Lu}/u`.

Answer (score 2):

Dar para fazer da seguinte forma com a função strtoupper:

```
<?php

$palavra = 'PALAVRA1';

if (strtoupper($palavra) == $palavra) {//TRUE
    echo 'Verdadeiro';
}

$palavra = 'pALaVRA1';

if (strtoupper($palavra) != $palavra) {//FALSE
    echo 'Falso';
}
```